# $f(z)$ entire function satisfying $f(z_{1} + {z_{2}})=f(z_{1})+f(z_{2})$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function satisfying $$f(z_{1} + z_{2})=f(z_{1})+f(z_{2}) $$ 
What is the form of f ?

$f$ is entire $\implies$ $f'(z)\  \forall z \implies f'(z)=f'(0)$
Now :
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h+0)-f(0)}{h}=0$$
which implies that $$f(z)= c $$
Isn't $f(z)=az$ is the correct answer for this question ?

Comment: Why is $f'(0) = 0$?

Comment: what's $f_{z_2}$ ?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this: [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation)

Comment: A constant $f$ does not fulfill $f(z_1 + z_2) = c \ne 2c = f(z_1) + f(z_2)$ if $c\ne 0$.

Comment: I have just edited the question .

Comment: How do you conclude the limit is zero?

Comment: I got $f'(z)=0 \Rightarrow f =c $ It's supposed to be $f=\alpha z $.

Comment: $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0) \Rightarrow f(0)= 0 $ so the limit is zero .

Comment: If you use $f(0) = 0$ you are still left with the limit of $f(h)/h$ which need not be $0$.

Comment: @topspin . See the comment above from LeBtz. If $f(x)=kx$ for all $x,$ then for $h\ne 0$ you have $(f(h(-f(0))/(h-0)=f(h)/h=kh/h=k.$

Comment: ok right limit of  $\frac{f(h)}{h}$ as h goes to 0 need not to be zero .

Answer (score 5):

Taking derivatives with respect to $z_1$ gives with the chain rule that 
$$ f'(z_1 + z_2) = f'(z_1) $$
for all $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbf C$. Hence there is some $a \in \mathbf C$ such that  $f'(z) = a$ for all $z \in \mathbf C$. Therefore $f(z) = az+b$ for some $b \in \mathbf C$. We have 
$$ f(z_1 + z_2) = az_1 + az_2 + b \stackrel!= az_1 + az_2 + 2b = f(z_1) + f(z_2) $$
This holds iff $b = 0$, hence $f(z) = az$ for all $z\in \mathbf C$.

Answer (score 4):

We have $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$, hence $f(0)=0$,

For $z \in \mathbb C$:

$\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=\frac{f(h)}{h}=\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \to f'(0)$ for $h \to 0$,

hence $f'(z)=f'(0)$ for all $z$.

Thus $f'$ is constant.